# Using abstract library in c++

Tags: c++, cmake, abstract-class

I have a library that is abstracted and basically looks like this:

A.h

```
namespace N {
    class A
}
```

B.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef B
#define B
#include "A.h" 
namespace N {
    class B: Public A
}
#endif
```

And the library is referenced in the CMakelists.txt like this:

```
global_add_library(libN A.cpp B.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libN someLibraries)
```

Now I have the `main` file which looks like this:

```
#include <libN/A.h>
#include <libN/B.h>

N::A a* = new A();
N::B b* = new B();
```

And its `CMakelists.txt` looks like this:

```
global_add_exectubale(application somemainccpfiles.cpp)
target_link_libraries(application libN)
```

What i am getting is an error saying

```
error: ISO C++ forbids deceleration of 'B' with no type.
```

So i am thinking that the B.h file isnt included properly? But why when the deceleration of `A` is just fine?

Any ideas?

EDIT: So I found out what the original problem was, the combination of the `pragma once` and the `ifndef` meant it wasn't compiling properly. When I removed the pragma once it was fixed. But now the question is why is that? Shouldn't it have worked even with both?

Comment: Given that none of this is real code, it's difficult to say...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth how did you know :0, but yeah, I cant post my real code cause its part of my work and has IP restrictions. But I'm not doing anything obviously wrong with the includes?

Comment: Is there maybe something going wrong during preprocessing? Maybe a problem with include guards?

Comment: @Ben: Assuming your inclusion guards are correct (`B.h`'s inclusion guards don't match `A.h`'s, do they?), and `A` and `B` are actually defined in their headers (and not just declared), there isn't anything obviously wrong.

Comment: @Ben: Even if you can't post the actual code, you should still try to post valid code.

Comment: @Cornstalks `A.h` never includes `B.h` so there should be no need to forward declare should there? Also the classes `A` and `B` are declared in the headers and defined in `A.cpp` and `B.cpp`, is that a problem?

Comment: @Ben: There shouldn't be a need for forward declaration, but you need to make sure inclusion guards aren't conflicting. Also, you need to define the classes in the header (but you can simply declare member functions in the header and define the member functions in the cpp). Declaring the classes with no definition will certainly cause issues if you try to instantiate one or the other.

Comment: @Cornstalks Yep, so i am pretty sure it is all above board. The classes work ok when included directly ie: #include A.h, B.h in main but it doesn't seem to be working with the CMake global library style?

Comment: @Cornstalks I have edited the question, i found the problem but im not sure why it was a problem.

Comment: @Ben: are your inclusion guards really the same as your class name? I hope not... Does `A.h` have any inclusion guards? I hope so... I also don't know why you're mixing both `#pragma once` and `#ifndef` style inclusion guards... just use one or the other, there's no reason to use both.

Comment: Also, this question would be infinitely easier to answer if you really took Marcelo Cantos's suggestion seriously and made a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/). Right now it's kinda like shooting in the dark with guesswork because little details can be incredibly important. I know you can't post your actual project code, but you could make a minimal example that exhibits the same behavior and post that.

Comment: Well removing #pragma once fixed it so im not sure what else you need to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include "A.h" 
namespace N {
    class B: Public A
}
```

Your included "A.h" but in other file it was "libN/A.h"

Comment: But if `B.h` and `A.h` are in the same folder, it should be ok for `B.h` to say `A.h` (without the `libN/` part).

Comment: That is correct, because im using CMake the code is in different directories and therefore I have set it up to be added like a library.